# how to transform the string into a dict in python?

Tags: python

```
app=related_query&type=json&src=sm_rec&count=20&sc=structure_web_info&uid=d4a048cc49a11ad0f98d83608c44b554%7C26858319344%7C%7C1508669758&uuid=d4a048cc49a11ad0f98d83608c44b554%7C26858319344%7C%7C1508669758&query=%E5%8E%86%E5%8F%B2%E6%B4%BB%E4%B8%A4%E7%99%BE%E5%B2%81%E4%BB%A5%E4%B8%8A%E7%9A%84&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.360doc.cn%2Farticle%2F150887_537727792.html&from=ucframe&title=%E5%8E%86%E5%8F%B2%E4%B8%8A%E6%9C%80%E9%95%BF%E5%AF%BF%E7%9A%84%E4%BA%BA%2C%E6%B4%BB%E5%88%B0%E4%B8%A4%E7%99%BE%E5%B2%81%E7%9A%84%E5%A5%A5%E7%A7%98&weini_sn=0

In [38]: line[str].split('&')
Out[38]:
['app=related_query',
 'type=json',
 'src=sm_rec',
 'count=20',
 'sc=structure_web_info',
 'uid=d4a048cc49a11ad0f98d83608c44b554%7C26858319344%7C%7C1508669758',
 'uuid=d4a048cc49a11ad0f98d83608c44b554%7C26858319344%7C%7C1508669758',
 'query=%E5%8E%86%E5%8F%B2%E6%B4%BB%E4%B8%A4%E7%99%BE%E5%B2%81%E4%BB%A5%E4%B8%8A%E7%9A%84',
 'url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.360doc.cn%2Farticle%2F150887_537727792.html',
 'from=ucframe',
 'title=%E5%8E%86%E5%8F%B2%E4%B8%8A%E6%9C%80%E9%95%BF%E5%AF%BF%E7%9A%84%E4%BA%BA%2C%E6%B4%BB%E5%88%B0%E4%B8%A4%E7%99%BE%E5%B2%81%E7%9A%84%E5%A5%A5%E7%A7%98',
 'weini_sn=0',
 'bucket=']
```

How to transform the original string into a dictionary which has key value. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: `d = {(sp.split('=')[0], sp.split('=')[1]) for sp in line[str].split('&')}`

Comment: there are many answers for `json` to `dict` on the web.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis its not a json he has...its a string and then he has a list of strings..

Comment: @alexisdevarennes At least the title says `dict`. Not sure what the desired output is.

Comment: the title says string to dict

Comment: also your one liner would not work if a param has an empty value. 'bucket='

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't parse this manually; Python has the `urllib.parse.parse_qs` function that does exactly what you want.

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs
parse_qs(line)
```

In Python 2 this is in the `urlparse` module:

```
from urlparse import parse_qs
```

Comment: Since Python 3 has been available for almost nine years now I tend to assume people are using it unless they say otherwise.